# data of extended component is undefined when used in data of extending component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a component (single file component):

```
// Cat.vue
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            actionsPredefined: {
                eat () => (console.log('eat')),
                purr () => (console.log('purr')),
                meow () => (console.log('meow')),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is extended by:

```
// Lion.vue
export default {
    extends: Cat,

    data() {
        return {
            actions: {
                eat: this.actionsPredefined.eat, // is undefined - why?
                purr: this.actionsPredefined.purr, // is undefined - why?
                roar () => (console.log('roar'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I use Lion.vue I get:

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'eat' of
>   undefined"

So looks like `this.actionsPredefined` is undefined in Lion.vue.

What is the correct way here to selectively merge `actionsPredefined` of extended component (Cat.vue) with `actions` of extending component (Lion.vue)?

In Lion.vue, when I move `actions` from `data` to `computed` Vue knows what `this.actionsPredefined` is, but I cannot move it to `computed` (because I need to be able to change `actions` by other methods and changing computed values...is obviously against the idea of using computed values and would not work).

I can also set `actions` empty in `Lion.vue` data and only populate them with `predefinedActions` in `created()` hook and it will work, but somehow it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't think so - I can still access `this.actionsPredefined` in computed and in created hook. Then what is the correct approach in such cases?

Comment: Why not just make these methods and then you can override or add as needed? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLLQKo?editors=1010

Comment: but Lions cannot meow ;) With this approach Lion inherits `meow` as well, and only Cat should have `meow` `action`. That's why I need selective inheritance.

Comment: If you want to pick and choose methods, I think I wouldn't use extends at all, and would have a set of predefined methods I could import. https://codesandbox.io/s/r7x9lpln5m

Comment: Agree, it's cleaner. But this code here is just an example, a simplified abstraction - my real `actions` are more complex objects and not as attractive... and most importantly have reference to `this` (component), not sure if `this` in imported modules would point correctly to component by which it was imported.

Comment: Methods are bound to the Vue when the Vue instance is created, so `this` inside a method will refer to the Vue (assuming the method is not defined with an arrow function, which is generally a mistake). See updated sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Vue invokes the `data` function of the subcomponent (`Lion`) *before* it calls the `data` function of the supercomponent (`Cat`). Data properties defined in `Cat` won't be available on the instance at that time.

> I can also set empty `actions` in Lion.vue data and populate them only in `created()` hook and it will work, but somehow it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Why not? What difference does it make if you initialize `actions` in the `data` hook verses the `created` hook?

Comment: It just feels cleaner to keep data in `data()`, rather than in some method used in created hook. I also thought Vue provides some other ways to handle such cases, seems like a common case...

Comment: Unfortunately there's no possible way you can access `actionsPredefined` from `data()` in `Lion`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own tests, and here is what I have found

Extends works fine if you do not create `data` object on the child class, i.e:

```
//Lion
<script>
import Cat from './cat';

export default {
  extends: Cat,
  created() {
    this.actionsPredefined.purr(); //this prints purr
  }
}

</script>
```

It also works fine if you define the `data` and their inherited properties as arrow functions, i.e:

```
<script>
import Cat from './cat';

export default {
  extends: Cat,
  data() {
    return {
      actions: {
        eat: () => this.actionsPredefined.eat(), 
        purr: () => this.actionsPredefined.purr(),
        roar: (console.log('roar'))
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.actions.eat(); // eat
    this.actions.purr(); // purr
    this.actions.roar; // roar
  }
}

</script>
```

And the Cat component:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        actionsPredefined: {
          eat: () => (console.log('eat')),
          purr: () => (console.log('purr')),
          meow: () => (console.log('meow')),
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `actionsPredefined` are available in Lion's created hook either way... But function that's calling a function, rathen than direct reference to a function is clever, didn't thought about that. By the way it doesn't have to be an arrow function, it's only about the reference.